# Java-Guardar HashSet en diferentes metodos

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Buenas tardes estoy realizando un programa para un ejercicio que trata sobre crear un menú para un taller de coches en el que se pueden registrar coches, mostrarlos, marcarlos como reparados y mostrarlos.

He creado el menú y dos métodos uno para registrar los coches una vez registrados se muestran todos los coches sin repetir matricula con HashSet y otro método que no consigo terminar en el que debo indicar los coches reparados, pero no consigo guardar los coches del método anterior para usarlos en el método de reparados. Además tengo un problema con listadoCoches.size en el `do while` que no logro resolver. ¿Alguna idea?

Adjunto código:

**Main**:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int preguntaMenu;
    System.out.println("***Bienvenido al programa de registro de coches***");

    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
    System.out.println("Que operación desea realizar? Introduzca una opcion:\n1.Registrar un coche\n2.Marcar como reparado\n3.Salir");
    preguntaMenu = lector.nextInt();

    if(preguntaMenu == 1){
    registrarCoche();
    }
    else if (preguntaMenu == 2){
    menuReparados();
    }

    }while (preguntaMenu != 3);
    System.out.println("Fin");
}

public static void registrarCoche() {
    //creamos el HashSet de Coche ya que el hashset hace que no se muestren los valores duplicados
            HashSet <Coche> listadoCoches = new HashSet<Coche>();

            String model;
            String color;
            String marca;
            int nPuertas;
            String matricula;
            String cilindrada;
            int fechaMatricula;
            String respuesta;

            Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

            //empezamos un bucle mientras el usuario desee insertar mas usuarios
            do {    
                System.out.println("Quiere registrar un coche?(S/N)");
                respuesta = lector.next();

                //si la respuesta es s volvera a preguntar nombre y suelo sino dirá gracias
                if (respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {

                    System.out.println("Indique la matricula:");
                    matricula = lector.next();

                    System.out.println("Indique el anyo de matriculacion:(solo el anyo)");
                    fechaMatricula = lector.nextInt();

                    System.out.println("Cual es el modelo del coche?");
                    model = lector.next();

                    System.out.println("Indique su color:");
                    color = lector.next();

                    System.out.println("Indique la Marca del vehiculo");
                    marca = lector.next();

                    System.out.println("Introduzca la cilindrada del vehiculo: ");
                    cilindrada = lector.next();

                    System.out.println("Cuantas puertas tiene el vehiculo?");
                    nPuertas = lector.nextInt();

                    listadoCoches.add(new Coche(model,color,marca,nPuertas,matricula,cilindrada,fechaMatricula));

                }

            }while(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")); //mientras la respuesta sea s


                //imprimimos el listado de coches el hashset es recorrido por un for
                System.out.println("\n**Coches pendientes de reparacion**");
                for(Coche c: listadoCoches) {   
                    System.out.println("\n"+c.mostrarInfo());
                }   
                System.out.println("\n************************\n");
}

    public static void menuReparados() {
        String matricula;
        HashSet <Coche> listadoCoches = new HashSet<Coche>();

        for(Coche c: listadoCoches) {   
            System.out.println("\n"+c.mostrarInfo());
        }   
        System.out.println("Tiene "+listadoCoches.size()+" coches pendientes de reparacion");

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
        System.out.println("Introduzca la matricula del coche que desea reparar");
        matricula = lector.nextLine();

        }while(listadoCoches.size() > 0 );
        System.out.println("No hay ningun coche para reparar");
        }
}
```

**Objeto Coche**:

```
public class Coche {
//variables
private String model;
private String color;
private String marca;
private int nPuertas;
private String matricula;
private String  cilindrada;
private int fechaMatricula;

//constructor
public Coche(String model, String color, String marca, int nPuertas, String matricula, String cilindrada,
        int fechaMatricula) {
    this.model = model;
    this.color = color;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.nPuertas = nPuertas;
    this.matricula = matricula;
    this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
    this.fechaMatricula = fechaMatricula;
}

//getters y setters

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}



public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}



public String getColor() {
    return color;
}



public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}



public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}



public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}



public int getnPuertas() {
    return nPuertas;
}



public void setnPuertas(int nPuertas) {
    this.nPuertas = nPuertas;
}



public String getMatricula() {
    return matricula;
}



public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
    this.matricula = matricula;
}



public String getCilindrada() {
    return cilindrada;
}



public void setCilindrada(String cilindrada) {
    this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
}



public int getFechaMatricula() {
    return fechaMatricula;
}



public void setFechaMatricula(int fechaMatricula) {
    this.fechaMatricula = fechaMatricula;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((matricula == null) ? 0 : matricula.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Coche other = (Coche) obj;
    if (matricula == null) {
        if (other.matricula != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!matricula.equals(other.matricula))
        return false;
    return true;
}

//metodo mostrar info
public String mostrarInfo() {
    return "Matricula: "+matricula+"\nFecha de matriculacion: "+fechaMatricula+"\nModelo: "+model+"\nColor: "+color+"\nMarca: "+marca+
            "\nCilindrada: "+cilindrada+"\nNumero de Puertas: "+nPuertas;
}
}
```

Comment: Si la lista esta dentro de un metodo, entonces al salir del metodo dejara de existir ;).. tenes que ponerla a nivel de la clase para que todos los metodos la vean

Comment: Como seria eso ?

Comment: Public class main es como cualquier otra clase. si en una clase queres que todos los metodos accedan a una propiedad, donde escribis la misma?

Comment: como public no? es que no me han explicado eso muy bien en clase aun :) a ver si lo entiendo en vez de colocar private en la clase coche debo quitarlo para que todos los metodos puedan acceder te refieres a eso ? o a que haga algo en la clase coche?

Comment: La respuesta de @gbianchi es correcta pero por favor aclara qué es lo que te falla. Por ejemplo, el problema de `listadoCoches.size()` en el do-while, ¿Cuál es?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad si te lo explicaron. Fijate que hiciste justamente lo que tenes que hacer en la clase coche.

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Coche {
    //variables
    private String matricula;
```

Esa variable (o propiedad) matricula, puede ser accedida por cualquier metodo dentro de la clase coche.

Por ejemplo la accedes aca:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((matricula == null) ? 0 : matricula.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```

o aca:

```
//metodo mostrar info
public String mostrarInfo() {
    return "Matricula: "+matricula+"\nFecha de matriculacion: "+fechaMatricula+"\nModelo: "+model+"\nColor: "+color+"\nMarca: "+marca+
            "\nCilindrada: "+cilindrada+"\nNumero de Puertas: "+nPuertas;
}
```

Ahora que lo que pasa, es que hay algo que se llama Ambito de una variable, y es la visibilidad que tiene la misma dentro de tu programa.

La variable matricula, al ser privada, solo puede ser vista dentro de la clase coche. Pero al estar definida al nivel de clase (no dentro de un metodo) puede ser vista por todos los metodos de la clase.

Ahora, veamos tu lista de coches:

```
public static void registrarCoche() {
    //creamos el HashSet de Coche ya que el hashset hace que no se muestren los valores duplicados
    HashSet <Coche> listadoCoches = new HashSet<Coche>();
```

Esta definida dentro de registrarCoche.. entonces solo vive dentro de ese metodo. Y al acabarse el metodo, desaparece con todo su contenido.

Tu main, es otra clase, asi como la clase coche. Es un caso especial, ya que es el punto de entrada de tu programa. Pero nada impide que tengas variables a nivel de la clase.

Lo que tenes que hacer es sacar ese HashSet de los procedimientos, y ponerlo a nivel de la clase, asi:

```
public class Main {
    Static HashSet <Coche> listadoCoches = new HashSet<Coche>();
```

Y ahi si, todos los metodos podran acceder a ese listado.

Comment: Lo he puesto anteriormente pero en el listado.add se me subraya en rojo como que no puede acceder

Comment: donde esta eso que decis?

Comment: En el main antes de main string args entre class main y eso he colocado el hashset y lo he eliminado de los métodos y listadoCoches.add se me subraya en rojo

Comment: Lo pusiste como static? cual es el error que tira eso rojo?

Comment: puse el public class Main{ y abajo HashSet <Coche> listadoCoches = new HashSet<Coche>(); y luego abajo public static void main(String[] args) { y quite de los metodos el hashset y me dice que el error es cannot make a static reference to the non-static field listadoCoches

Comment: y buscaste que quiere decir ese error? porque es justamente el problema.. tus metodos estaticos no puede acceder a una propiedad estatica ;).. ahi edito la respuesta con la variable corregida

Comment: Hola disculpa la tardanza en responder ayer por la tarde entendí le error, no sabia donde tenía que colocar el static, muchas gracias!